# Snapshot lost in xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, version-control, xcode7

Updating my Xcode to Xcode 7 made me lose "Create/Restore Snapshot" options. How can I use "Source Control" to get the same functionalities that I got From "snapshot".ie, create a snapshots of a Working Conditions and Reverting back to the Versions that I want.
I am working on a project and I don't think I have checked "Create Local Repository on My Mac" during startup. I have tried reading many of the tutorials and none of them seemed to help me

Answer (score 0):

There are no snapshots in Xcode 7. Although it's totally different tool, you can use git or other version control system to achieve similar results as snapshots.

To start using git you have to run `git init` in your project's root directory. Hidden folder named `.Git` will be created. All changes made to your project will be stored in this directory as a tree of objects. You don't even have to look into this directory for begging.

To manage git tree you can use `git` command-line tool but I think it would be easier for you to use any GUI for that. I'm using SourceTree for example.

To make a long story short,when you have some part of jour job done, you create commit in git. Then you can switch between those commits, delete them, even reordering. You can also push your git tree to remote server to cooperate with other developers.

I would start by reading this git [documentation](https://git-scm.com/doc).